# Task was cancelled when trying to download file from WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I got the error "*Task was cancelled*" when I'm trying to download a zip file from Web API. What am I doing wrong ?

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var attachment in item)
        {
            var entry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(attachment.ItemAnalisado.Arquivo.Nome, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            {
                var dadosArquivo = File.ReadAllBytes(
                Path.Combine(CaminhoImagens,
                attachment.ItemAnalisado.Arquivo.ProcessoId.ToString(),
                attachment.ItemAnalisado.Arquivo.SubPastaId.ToString(),
                attachment.ItemAnalisado.Arquivo.Id.ToString()));
                stream.Write(dadosArquivo, 0, dadosArquivo.Length);
                //stream.Position = 0;
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    ms.Position = 0;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
    ms.Dispose();
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "teste.zip";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: How much time it takes to create a zip archive? Maybe task was cancelled because of timeout.

Comment: Why do you call 'stream.Close()' inside that using? It should close automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: And why do you call ms.Dispose() immediately after setting the response content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this error while trying to download an Excel file calling my API. I didn't had ATP implemented on this method so it was confusing at first. This was my initial code:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] string id, [FromUri] SurveyReportRequestType requestType) {
    byte[] excelData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Boobs out!");
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(excelData))
    {
        result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
        {
            FileName = "Data.xls"
        };
    }
    return ResponseMessage(result);
}
```

After thinking and making some changes this came up:

...

```
byte[] excelData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Boobs aout!");

HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
var stream = new MemoryStream(excelData);
result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
{
    FileName = "Data.xls"
};
return ResponseMessage(result);
```

...

As you can see I was enclosing the *stream* inside an **using** statement. This was causing that the request wasn't being completed since the content was not available for the response.

Comment: To put it shortly: do **NOT** dispose content stream in the controller. Web API will take care of it.